# OverloadedLabels: No instance for IsLabel on record data type

Tags: haskell, record

In the code below,

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLabels #-}
module Foo where

data R = R { x :: Int }

g :: Int
g = #x (R { x = 1 })
```

I expected this to type-check, but instead I get:

```
foo.hs:7:5: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.OverloadedLabels.IsLabel "x" (R -> Int))
        arising from the overloaded label ‘#x’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: #x
      In the expression: #x (R {x = 1})
      In an equation for ‘g’: g = #x (R {x = 1})
```

Given the [Overloaded Record Fields](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0023-overloaded-record-fields.rst#id8) proposal, I expected there to be a built-in instance of `IsLabel "x" (R -> Int)`.  Is this still the case or does the implementation deviate from the proposal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `IsLabel` instance for `OverloadedLabels` in (at least current) base (cf. discussion [here](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/6#issuecomment-276150270)).
You may want to use some libraries which define an orphan instance such as [generic-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-2.0.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Labels.html).
Of cource, you can define it by yourself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.Records
import GHC.OverloadedLabels

instance HasField x r a => IsLabel x (r -> a) where
  fromLabel = getField @x
```